# WCF anything in the endPointBehavior cancels the metaData exposure?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, web-config

This is my web.config file:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding 
      name="ExtremeBinding" 
      maxBufferSize="12354000" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="12354000" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="WcfService3.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint 
      address="" 
      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="ExtremeBinding"
      contract="WcfService3.IService1" 
      behaviorConfiguration="epBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="epBehavior">

    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

If I keep it like this, and run the WCF Test Client, everything works fine.

But if I add anything to the endPoint Behavior, for example:

```
    <behavior name="epBehavior">
      <callbackDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
```

the WCF Test Client fails with the Error:

```
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
```

It seems as though it doesn't matter what I put within the . For example:

```
<behavior name="epBehavior">
    <webHttp/>
</behavior>
```

It's clear to me that I missing something fundamental, but I can't figure what it is.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why this happens, but I think you can fix this by adding a serviceMetadata behavior:

```
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="NewBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" 
     httpsGetUrl="https://myComputerName/myEndpoint" />
  </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This is from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx

Comment: the problem is in the endpoint behavior, not the service one. Really weird.
I have some weird stuff on my endpoint behavior (certificate thingy) and works. Hate cryptic or inaccurate WCF errors.